# cmd control command recognition in java

Tags: java, testing, cmd

I am just wondering if there is a way, after launching "control wuaucpl.cpl" from my java script, to recognize if it has ran, or if it was blocked via active directory, or security settings. I have tried launching it with error streams, but so far I haven't seen any way of actually telling if it has opened up and ran or not. With similar tests I would just run a tasklist and check there to see if the process was running, but of course it comes up under explorer.exe and hence, would be impossible to tell.

EDIT:
This can also apply for any cmd control commands. EG: "control desk.cpl" or "control appwiz.cpl"

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.